# Find complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors then find the general real valued solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$A = \Bigg ( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & 3 \end{array}  \Bigg )$

I have already found the eigenvectors and eigenvalues:

$\lambda = 2 \pm i\sqrt{3}$ and $v_1 = [\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}, 1 ]$ and $v_2 = [\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}, 1 ]$

I am not sure how to get the real valued solution from this? Does it have to due with Eulers formula?

Comment: I notice you have tagged this question as differential-equations, what differential equations do these eigenvalues pertain to?

Comment: $\frac{dY}{dt} = \Bigg( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & 3 \end{array} \Bigg) Y = [x'(t),y't(t)] = [x - 2y, 2x - 3y] $

Answer (score 3):

For complex eigenvalues, we get a solution of the form:
$e^{(2+\sqrt3i)t}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\\1\end{pmatrix}=e^{2t}(cos(\sqrt3t)+isin(\sqrt3t))\begin{pmatrix}-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\\1\end{pmatrix}$
Then expand to make it look like $\begin{pmatrix}  & & \\ & & \end{pmatrix}+i\begin{pmatrix}  & & \\ & & \end{pmatrix}$
The general solution will be $x(t)=c_1\begin{pmatrix}  & & \\ & & \end{pmatrix}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}  & & \\ & & \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First determin the complex fundamental system $Y=[v_1e^{\lambda_1t},v_2e^{\lambda_2t}]$

Now, determine the real $Y_R$ and imaginary $Y_I$ part of $Y$ (check that both columns of $Y_R$/$Y_I$ are multiples of each other). Take the first column of $Y_R$ and the first column of $Y_I$ and build your real fundamental system $Y_{real}$.

The general solution is given by $y=Y_{real}\cdot[c_1,c_2]^T$